# How to run Anaconda Python on sudo

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, root, anaconda, sudo

Currently using AWS to run some tests on a machine learning project. I would like to run Python scripts without internet (via root) because the internet bandwidth is extremely limited. I try to run the convnets.py script by doing

```
sudo python convnets.py >> output
```

But that does not work, as Anaconda does not use PYTHONPATH, making it impossible for root to find the Anaconda Python environment. So errors like "cannot import" and "module not found" are thrown.

How do I set this up so I can get Anaconda and sudo to play fair together?

Comment: Are you sure that `python` is pointing to Anaconda's python? Chances are that it is not since `sudo` has a different `PATH`. Try `sudo /path/to/anaconda/bin/python convnets.py`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because using `sudo` uses a different `PATH` than your typical environment, you need to be sure to specify that you want to use Anaconda's python interpreter rather than the system python. You can check which one is being run with the following command

```
sudo which python
```

To fix this, and point to Anaconda's python interpreter, specify the full path to the correct interpreter.

```
sudo /path/to/anaconda/bin/python convnets.py >> output
```

If you do this, you should be able to access all of the modules managed by anaconda.

On the other hand, if you have an Anaconda environment created

```
conda create --name $ENVIRONMENT_NAME python
```

You can activate it prior to running your command

```
sudo source activate $ENVIRONMENT_NAME && python convnets.py >> output
```

Comment: Great, this worked! Thanks, love it when the solution is so simple :)

Comment: @d4tm4x it worked for me